# Use command line to upload hex code to teensy.ex

Tags: uploading, bootloader, teensy, command-line

I need a command line implementation for uploading code to Teensy-LC through Windows 8.1 operating system
I know Paul has not released support for command line for Teensy-LC yet but i would like to know if any work has been done by anybody else in this regard.

I asked [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/use-command-line-to-upload-program-through-hex-file-to-teensy-lc) and [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18679/is-it-possible-to-create-a-standalone-exe-which-can-burn-the-code-into-a-teensy). But all these solutions include

> sending the hex file to the user.
>
> Asking him to open Teensy.exe
>
> Asking him to upload the hex file into Teensy.ex
>
> Asking him to run teensy_reboot.exe

So is it possible to create an installer of a sort for this purpose which eliminates the user performing all these operations separately and a guided installer simply with Next->Next which does the entire job.

But I suppose that since Command Line installer is not available for windows I don't know if this is possible for impossible.

So if there is any way I can achieve an installer UI for Teensy-LC bootloader that would be perfect

**Other viable option**
If not that is it possible to make the entire process happen with the person not having direct access to the hex file.
Like sending a packaged installer or something
I am not sure how this would happen but if there is any possible way please help me out

Comment: You might be able to run the teensy.exe in the background, and [press the right button using code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223872/programatically-press-a-button-on-another-application-c-windows)

Comment: But this is a third party application I don't have access to. Secondly the question that you pointed me to does not have an answer yet. So even that person was not able to press button of a third party application in background. is there any other way?

Comment: Most applications use the windows api to create buttons. E.g. screenreaders are able to access this information, and read out button info, and also "click" on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is starting to drift off topic for this site, but the best solution for making an automated programming utility for the Teensy on Windows, short of writing one yourself, would be to use some kind of UI automation framework to automate the process described in [my earlier answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/19845/11086). My favorite one that I have used in the past is [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It has tools to inspect applications so that you can programmatically click buttons and fill out fields. There are even ways of having it run programs without them being visible to the user. There are plenty of tutorials on the web on how to use AutoIt so I would suggest googling for that. If you have further questions on how to do that, they would be more appropriate on a site other than Arduino.SE.